# mysql database export not working with /dev/null 2>&1

Tags: mysql

I try to create a script for MySQL database export, and I want to make it work silently. To make it work, I use this command

```
mysqldump -u $username -p$password $database_name > $(pwd)/sql_backups/$database_name_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").sql  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This command just simply create a .sql file but not export that database. When I dont use `> /dev/null 2>&1` it is working.

[THE CODE](https://github.com/mossygr/mysqlexporter/blob/master/mysqlexport.sh#L82)

Answer (score 1):

create .bat file and try this :

```
set "HOST=yourhost"
set "USER=youruser"
set "PASSWORD=yourpassword"
set "DATABASE=yourdatabase"
set "DB_FILE=dumptest.sql"


echo "Dump structure"
mysqldump --host=%HOST% --user=%USER% --password=%PASSWORD% --single-transaction  %DATABASE% -R > %DB_FILE%
echo "Dump structure terminer"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I want to export sql database silently but when i use /dev/null 2>&1 it doesn't export the database, it only creates a file .sql